# How do I join this numbers together?

Tags: javascript, join

```js
function expandedForm(num) {
    let len = num.toString().length;
    let n = num.toString().split("");
    let result = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        result += n[i] + "0".repeat(len -1 -i).join(" + ");
    }

    return result;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to separate numbers like this:

1220 = "1000 + 200 + 20"

221 = "200 + 20 + 1"

I have written the code (not the perfect one) where it gets me all the necessary values but I struggle with joining them together with "+". I tried using .join() but it did not work.

Comment: `.join()` needs a separator. Try `.join(" + ")`

Comment: Yeah of course I tried that one already.

Comment: And how exactly did you use `.join`? Please update your example. FWIW, there is no need to call `parseInt` if you don't use any of those values as numbers.

Comment: @FelixKling Like this

Comment: You could update this question to be a runnable snippet that actually demonstrates the problem. [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do](See How to add a snippet)

Comment: Right now I expect your code will elicit: `"Uncaught TypeError: \"0\".repeat(...).join is not a function"` Because `.join` is a function of an **array** e.g. `['a','b','c'].join('+')` is `"a+b+c"`.

Comment: Yes I get this exact error. So how should I format my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are a variety of approaches, here are some general tips for you:

- Probably don't want to output a `0` term unless the input number is exactly `0` (only a leading `0` term is relevant, because it will be the only such term)
- `str.split('')` can also be `[...str]`
- No need to split a string into an array to access a character `str.split('')[0]` can also be just `str[0]`
- Might want to assert that `num` is a whole number.
- Make sure you provide enough test cases in your question to fully define the behaviour of your function. (How to handle trailing zeros, interstitial zeros, leading zeros, etc. Whether the input can be a string.)

```js
function expandedForm(num) {
  const s = num.toString();
  const n = s.length - 1;
  const result = [...s]
    .map((char, index) => char + '0'.repeat(n - index))
    .filter((str, index) => !index || +str)
    .join(' + ');

  return result;
}

console.log(expandedForm(1220));
console.log(expandedForm(221));
console.log(expandedForm(10203));
console.log(expandedForm(0));
console.log(expandedForm(2n**64n));
```

Answer (score 1):

.join works on arrays only

```js
function expandedForm(num) {
    let len = num.toString().length;
    let n = num.toString().split("");
    let result = "";
    let arr=[];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = n[i] + '0'.repeat(len-1-i);
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
    
    let ans=arr.join('+');
    return ans;
}

console.log(expandedForm(1220))
```

Answer (score 0):

Join works with an array, not string. It stringifies two subsequent indexes for all indexes and you can decide what to add between them.

```
    function expandedForm(num) { // num = 321
        let len = num.toString().length;  // len = 3
        let n = num.toString().split(""); // [3,2,1]
        let result = [];
    
    
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            result.push(n[i] + "0".repeat(len -1 -i));  // pushing till result = ['300','20','10'] 
        }
       
    
        return num + ' = ' + result.join(' + '); 
      // connection result[0] + ' + ' result[1] + ' + ' result[2] 
    }
   expandedForm(321); // output: "321 = 300 + 20 + 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it

```js
let num = 221;
function expandedForm(num) {
    let len = num.toString().length;
    let n = num.toString().split("");
    let result = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let t = "0"
        t = t.repeat(len-1-i)
        if(result.length > 0){
          n[i] !== '0'? result += '+'+ n[i] + t : result 
        } else {
          n[i] !== '0'? result += n[i] + t : result 
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(expandedForm(2200))
console.log(expandedForm(num))
```

Comment: Yeah, it is great. I found out that not only .join() but the whole code was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

below would be my approach in a more mathimatical but clean code that you can adjust to your needs.

````
    let result = parseInt(num / 1000);
    return result ;
}

function x100( num ) {
    num = num % 1000;

    let result = parseInt( num / 100);
    return result;
}

function x10(num ) {
    num = num % 1000;
    num = num % 100;
    let result = parseInt(num /10);
    return result;
}

function x1( num ) {
    num = num % 1000;
    num = num % 100;
    num = num % 10;
    return num
}

num = 12150
console.log(num = `1000 x ${x1000(num)}, 100 x ${x100(num)}, 10 x ${x10(num)}`)```
````